# iAd is not working in my iphone application

Tags: iphone, iad

I add iAd functionality into to my code of iPhone application. My application is live now and available on app stores. May be at the time of app submission i forgot to do set up iAd network Setting. i.e. ( Enable iAds and forgot setting for to indicate whether your primary target audience is users under 17 years of age). now my application is live and not showing iAds. Is there any way from which i can check or enable the iAd functionality to this existing Application? Please anyone can help ?

Answer (score 1):

The best option which i feel you have is to release a new version of your app with the changes on itunesconnect in the iAd framework...So All the Best...